# What is the hierarchy/relationship between graphs and databases in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j

Using the neo4j browser, I am unable to do anything until I start a particular graph. Even selecting a database is only available after I start a graph. Are databases under graphs or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about the Neo4j Desktop UI. I agree that the terminology used by the UI is confusing.

What the Desktop UI calls a "Graph" is actually a **neo4j installation**. (By the way, "Graph" is just the *default name* for an installation -- you can specify a different name.)

The Desktop tool allows you to create multiple "Projects", and each Project can have multiple neo4j installations.

Comment: Just an FYI, the terminology in Neo4j Desktop is changing accordingly! Check the latest version of Neo4j Desktop to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

I will just add the official docs, maybe it will help.

In very simple terms as you ask: DATABASE -> GRAPH (I think this is more like DATABASE = GRAPH).

".. when Neo4j is installed and an instance created, it will be initiated with two databases – a system database and a default (neo4j) database. Launching Neo4j Browser will automatically point us to the neo4j default database".

https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/

1. After running default, switch to system database

   :use system
2. run

   SHOW DATABASES

Comment: Correct for now, a database only has a single graph, so at the moment they're equivalent. Multigraph features per database are being considered, however, so this may change in the future.